# index hyperlink not pointing to correct page

Tags: hyperref, indexing

In the MWE below, the hyperlink from the index page does not take you to the correct page to where the index is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}

\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,hypertexnames=false,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
% pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter

\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{1}
\section{1}
\lipsum
This is index ONE\index{One}
\newpage
This is index TWO\index{Two}


\backmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
%\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

If you click on the "2" in the index, you get taken to page ii instead of page 2 to where the index is.

Can you offer a solution so that if you click on the hyperlink in the index, you will be taken to the correct page?

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516267/compatibility-of-hypertexnames-false-and-indexes) is maybe related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, in Index, correct pagenumbers are displayed, but hyperref was pointing 3 pages before....

In my case, I solved it by putting a `\pagenumbering{roman}` directly after `\begin{document}`.

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

This seems to get the internal pagenumbering for `\makeindex` and hyperref straight.

Answer (score 3):

With `hypertexnames=false` also correct index links are disabled, use the default value `true` instead.

Option `breaklinks` does *not* magically add support for breaking links across lines, if the driver does not support this. Then the text is broken across lines, but the link areas are quite wrong.

The data for the PDF information keys should be set *after* package `hyperref` is loaded via `\hypersetup`. Otherwise LaTeX will hard expand the values and garbage can be the result.

Option setting `backref=true` and `pagebackref=true` is contradictory. Either use the former with section back references or the latter with page number back references.

Also I recommend package `bookmark` for faster updated bookmarks.

Comment: This is a more general answer than the accepted solution. Thanks!!